# Relation between two sets of range of functions

Tags: functions

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function such that $ \lim_{n \to \infty } f^n(x) $ exists for every $x \in R $, where  $f^n(x)=f \circ f^{n-1}(x) $ for $n \ge 2.$ Define $$ S=\{\lim_{n \to \infty }f^n(x): x\in R\}, T =\{x\in R:f(x)=x\}$$ Then which of the following is necessarily true?

$(A) S \subset T$
$(B) T \subset S$
$(C) S = T$
(D) None of the above

My effort:

Case 1: Taking $f(x) = k,$ any constant.
$f^2(x) = f\circ f(k)= f(k) =k$ repeating this process, we get $f^n(x) = k$, so $S=\{k\}$.  $f(x)=x$ will be true only for x=k, so $T=\{k\}$. Hence S=T.

Case 2: Taking $f(x) = x^2.    
f^n(x) = x^{2n}, S=\{\infty \}$.
$f(x) =x \Rightarrow x^2 - x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0, 1.$  $ T = \{0,1\}. S\ne T.$

So option D is correct. Can someone please suggest if my answer is correct? If not, please provide reason with example.

Comment: $T\subseteq S$ in any case. Next, let $x\in\Bbb R$ and then $f\big(\lim f^{(n)}(x)\big)=\lim f\big(f^{(n)}(x)\big)=\lim f^{(n+1)}(x)=\lim f^{(n)}(x)$, as continuity of $f$ gives $y_n\to y\implies f(y_n)\to f(y)$. So, $S=T$ in any case.

Comment: If you take $f(x)=x^2$, then $f^{(n)}(x)=x^{2n}\to \infty$ for all $|x|>1$, so $f$ doesn't satisfy the hypothesis that $\lim f^{(n)}(x)$ exists for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: But, your case $1$ is correct.